# symbol text string

Tags: text, symbols

Python.
Need to place the symbol (suppose "@") after every three comas in the text.
For example: text = "Reading practice to help you understand simple texts and find specific information in everyday material. Texts include emails, invitations, personal messages, tips, notices and signs. Texts include articles, reports, messages, short stories and reviews."

That should start, I guess, to divide on comas: st_text = text.split(",")  Is that right?
then to add certain symbol after every three got splited lines
Something like that?? - print('@'.join(st_text[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(st_tex), 3)))

But smth going wrong..

As the result must be: ""Reading practice to help you understand simple texts and find specific information in everyday material. Texts include emails, invitations, personal messages,@ tips, notices and signs. Texts include articles, reports,@ messages, short stories and reviews."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join function removes the commas from the text, so I tried other methods and this works:

```
text = "Reading practice to help you understand simple texts and find specific information in everyday material. Texts include emails, invitations, personal messages, tips, notices and signs. Texts include articles, reports, messages, short stories and reviews."
formatted_text = ''
count = 0 
for i in text:
    formatted_text = formatted_text + I
    if i == ',':
        count += 1
        if count == 3:
            formatted_text = formatted_text + '@'
            count = 0
print(formatted_text)
```

Comment: thank you!! the main issue - "count += 1 (counts every line) if count == 3: (when it reaches the3rd line we add the certain symbol). I noticed before that way through "count". I thought maybe there was a shorter way to solve. I got. Thank you.